# Is hacking spectres in the game mode 'Attrition' recommended?

Tags: titanfall, titanfall-2

When hacking a [spectre](http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/BRD-01_Spectre) in the game mode 'Attrition', you'll get points (about 4) for that and nearby spectres change sides and start following you. But they now can be killed by the enemy team.

Will the enemy team receive points for that? (making your points gained by hacking useless)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you hack a spectre, you get +1 point in attrition, the same as if you killed it. In addition, spectres tend to come in groups of 3 or 4, and if you hack one of them, you get the entire group. Often, this will be +3 points, which is a decent reward.

[image: animated GIF illustrating the above]

It or they will then follow you around to the best of their ability (note: they can jump; it is just slow). The spectre also has an updated nameplate referencing the player who hacked it.

If the enemy kills one of your spectres, they will then get +1.

While this arguably negates the gains of your original +1, it doesn't immediately negate any of the benefits.

**Advantages**

- spectre armies are cool, they fight for you
- you have a spotter
- you have cover
- you have an escort
- +1 for hacking them
- anything they kill is more points for your score
- they will meet up with you after respawn

**Disadvantages**

- you have something that shoots without considering tactics right next to you (they will shoot at a titan with their Volt, for example, giving away your position)
- there is a trail of AI with your name on it following you
- the other team now has an extra set of NPCs to dispatch for points
- takes time to hack

Is it recommended? It just depends on your gameplay. While hacking a spectre may cause an easy target, at that point in the match there are already many spectres as targets anyway. There is no detrimental aspect to hacking a spectre though.

Overall, it is just a fun aspect of the game. If you want to hack them, then do it. However, due to the time required of doing this, I have found that it can slow down your own personal score in the match if you attempt to seek them out. That said, it is still fun to make a spectre army, which is the point of the game anyway, right? :)

Comment: One advantage you didn't mention: After they are hacked, they then fight for you. If they then kill another Spectre or grunt, you get the points for those as well. While they don't last for ever (IE: get killed fairly easily), while they are yours there's a distinct possibility of gaining points to your total.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I thought that was kind of implicit, but I will edit it in.

Comment: I was just covering the bases. Good Pros/Cons writeup!

Comment: Thanks :) See edits. If you think of any others feel free to let me know. I was thinking of putting a small video together here for this, will see.

Comment: @TravisJ Why did you rollback the edit? I made that edit to ensure the image’s availability, as it was not uploaded to SE’s Imgur instance and a [change in Imgur’s TOS could cause the loss of that image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). (I also fixed some typos and spelling errors).

Comment: @galacticninja - Unfortunately the compressed image was too lossy. If the current video goes away, so be it, but I won't have my name attached to something that is probably a strobing risk.

Comment: @TravisJ It would have been helpful if you had mentioned that in the edit reason, and left the typo/spelling error fixes intact. I had to convert the GIF to a smaller size because SE’s Imgur instance has a 2 MiB limitation. Did you upload the GIF via an account on Imgur? If so, Imgur will not delete the GIF according to their TOS.

Comment: @galacticninja - I did not have the availability to type in an edit reason at that time sorry. I also did not see the other corrections. This GIF was not uploaded via an account. It was generated by giphy. I am sorry that the conversion took you time, I am sure it was well intentioned. The quality was just not well suited for that configuration.

Comment: @TravisJ I think it can be converted and still retain the quality, but there'd have to be multiple GIFs ≤ 2 MiB. If I have some time later, I will try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen from experimentation in private matches is that as you Jack spectres less A.I enemy's spawn in until the point in which no enemy A.Is spawn in and for some reason in private matches nearly all of the A.I come down by drop pod and not dropship, also I got around 260 points on a 40 minute private attrition match by myself and that included  hacking spectres although that's probably not the limit as my team accumulated a large amount of grunts that probably got around I would say 100 points themselves but they don't count so yeah. still spectres can be useful as they are basically grunts but with better armor (weaponry is to be debated) but have less tactical sense especially when hacked. overall I wouldn't recommend it as even an excessive number of them can get demolished by an Enemy pilot or Titan but it is cool, and by cool I mean funny cool like sneaking behind a pilot and putting a pilot sentry right behind them instead of assasanation.